# Drawing huge amount of lines

Tags: c++, graphics, line, raylib

My goal is to draw a huge amount of lines in real time. This minimal example is drawing 250000 lines with about 30 fps. Another approach is to draw 250000 capsules with about 14 fps dropping to finally 1 fps after some seconds. (The idea of the capsules is to control the weight of the lines afterwards). Both approaches look very slow to me.

Maybe the problem in this case is the connection between CPU and GPU. The grid is created again every frame. Is there an approach to only draw it again and not recreating it? Is this done with VOB?

What is a decent approach to draw line graphics in C++ with high speed? When taking a look at CAD-programs handling a really large amount of geometry, i guess this is based on Vulkan, Metal or other?

```
#include "raylib.h"
#include "rcamera.h"

int main() {
    const int screenWidth = 1280;
    const int screenHeight = 720;
    
    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "Test lines");
    
    SetTargetFPS(60);
    SetConfigFlags(FLAG_MSAA_4X_HINT);
    int display = GetCurrentMonitor();
    SetWindowSize(GetMonitorWidth(0), GetMonitorHeight(0));
    ToggleBorderlessWindowed();
    
    Camera3D camera = {0};
    camera.position = (Vector3){0.00f, -5.00f, 1.75f};
    camera.target = (Vector3){0.00f, 0.00f, 0.00f};
    camera.up = (Vector3){0.00f, 0.00f, 1.00f};
    camera.fovy = 60.0f;
    camera.projection = CAMERA_PERSPECTIVE;

    DisableCursor();
    
    // loop
    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        // update camera
        UpdateCamera(&camera, CAMERA_FREE);
        
        BeginDrawing();
            ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
            
            BeginMode3D(camera);
                // draw grid
                for (int x=-250; x<=250; x++){
                    for (int y=-250; y<=250; y++){
                        Vector3 start1;
                        start1.x = float(x+0.1f);
                        start1.y = float(y);
                        start1.z = 0.0f;
                        
                        Vector3 end1;
                        end1.x = float(x-0.1f);
                        end1.y = float(y);
                        end1.z = 0.0f;
                            
                        Vector3 start2;
                        start2.x = float(x);
                        start2.y = float(y+0.1f);
                        start2.z = 0.0f;
                        
                        Vector3 end2;
                        end2.x = float(x);
                        end2.y = float(y-0.1f);
                        end2.z = 0.0f;
                        
                        //DrawLine3D(start1, end1, LIGHTGRAY);
                        //DrawLine3D(start2, end2, LIGHTGRAY);
                        
                        DrawCapsule(start1, end1, 0.01f, 1, 1, BLACK);
                        DrawCapsule(start2, end2, 0.01f, 1, 1, BLACK);
                    }
                }
            EndMode3D();
            
            // fps
            DrawText(TextFormat("fps: %d", GetFPS()), 10.0f, 40.0f, 16, BLACK);
            
        EndDrawing();
    }
    CloseWindow();
    return 0;
}
```

Update: Thanks again for all your Feedback! I will take this in account for next projects. For my current issue i have decided to create a workaround. The idea is to fade out the lines, that are to far away to be visible anyway. So for anyone interested. This approach is not addressing the initial question but maybe it is working for some other cases:

```
#include "raylib.h"
#include "raymath.h"
#include "rcamera.h"
#include "iostream"

int main() {
    SetTraceLogLevel(7);
    SetTargetFPS(60);    
    const int screenWidth = 1280;
    const int screenHeight = 720;
    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "Test lines");
    SetConfigFlags(FLAG_MSAA_4X_HINT);
    int display = GetCurrentMonitor();
    SetWindowSize(GetMonitorWidth(0), GetMonitorHeight(0));
    ToggleBorderlessWindowed();
    
    Camera3D camera = {0};
    camera.position = (Vector3){0.00f, -5.00f, 1.75f};
    camera.target = (Vector3){0.00f, 0.00f, 0.00f};
    camera.up = (Vector3){0.00f, 0.00f, 1.00f};
    camera.fovy = 60.0f;
    camera.projection = CAMERA_PERSPECTIVE;

    DisableCursor();
    
    // loop
    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        // update camera
        UpdateCamera(&camera, CAMERA_FREE);
        
        BeginDrawing();
            ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
            
            BeginMode3D(camera);
                // draw grid
                int size = 25;
                for (int x=-size; x<=size; x++){
                    for (int y=-size; y<=size; y++){
                        // get position of the camera
                        // int is converting the position to fit the grid
                        // the grid is moving with the camera now
                        int pos_x = camera.position.x;
                        int pos_y = camera.position.y;
                        
                        Vector3 start1;
                        start1.x = pos_x + float(x+0.1f);
                        start1.y = pos_y + float(y);
                        start1.z = 0.0f;
                        
                        Vector3 end1;
                        end1.x = pos_x + float(x-0.1f);
                        end1.y = pos_y + float(y);
                        end1.z = 0.0f;
                            
                        Vector3 start2;
                        start2.x = pos_x + float(x);
                        start2.y = pos_y + float(y+0.1f);
                        start2.z = 0.0f;
                        
                        Vector3 end2;
                        end2.x = pos_x + float(x);
                        end2.y = pos_y + float(y-0.1f);
                        end2.z = 0.0f;
                        
                        // fade out the lines that are further away from the camera
                        float dist = Vector3Distance(camera.position, start1);
                        float alpha = Remap(dist, 0, size, 255, 0);
                        if (alpha > 255){alpha = 255;}
                        if (alpha < 0){alpha = 0;}
                        DrawLine3D(start1, end1, Color{0, 0, 0, (unsigned char)alpha});
                        DrawLine3D(start2, end2, Color{0, 0, 0, (unsigned char)alpha});
                    }
                }
            EndMode3D();
            
            // fps
            DrawText(TextFormat("fps: %d", GetFPS()), 10.0f, 40.0f, 16, BLACK);
            
        EndDrawing();
    }
    CloseWindow();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Render to an offscreen buffer (texture) on a background thread (and swap the texture every now and then), or setup a 3D geometry of lines and let the 3D engine figure out the rendering (this is the way things are done with Vulkan/OpenGL and 3D engines in general)

Comment: Just a stupid idea, BeginDrawing and EndDrawing is like write on a second buffer and swap it when done. Can't you create a boolean flag, set it to false initially, call BeginDrawing/EndDrawing blocks if the flag is false and once setting up grid is done one, just set it to true after EndDrawing. Next time, it will NOT do writing to new buffer and swapping, just displaying current buffer. Not sure, but give it a try.

Comment: Do you really have to use raylib?

Comment: first of all don't draw capsules to get a thicker line, use rectangles instead and don't waste your GPU power, second look into instanced rendering, i see it is possible in raylib docs, otherwise you can use raw opengl/vulkan with instanced rendering and compare the performance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers!

What do you mean with 3D geometry? Maybe creating a mesh? Yes, this could be a possible solution. I don't have to use raylib. I am familiar with it, but if its better to switch to another library, it would be fine of course. Do you have a suggestion for me?

Thanks for the idea with the bool. This approach sounds interesting, but i guess the screen needs to be redrawn at least in raylib.

Using rectangles is also an approach to try, but actually even the lines a very slow.

Do someone maybe has a link to a minimal example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Raylib has an [example of instanced rendering](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/master/examples/shaders/shaders_mesh_instancing.c). In your case the mesh would be a simple triangle pair that represents a line and every individual line would have a transform that moves and rotates the endpoints correctly. The vertex shader would simply apply the transform passed in, and the fragment shader would simply render the color provided in the material. Searching for "opengl rendering instanced lines" gives me good results such as [this](https://wwwtyro.net/2019/11/18/instanced-lines.html)

Comment: Note that you do not need to go full instanced rendering right away; you could simply create an OpenGL vertex buffer with [x1,y1,x2,y2] indices and use the built-in GL_LINES drawing primitive to draw the whole bunch in one go. That will already give you a few orders of magnitude improvement as opposed to drawing them one at a time.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your feedback. I will check this out :)